# Booting a Linux environment CD on a Macbook Pro

Tags: linux, osx, macintosh

Im trying to boot my Linux environment on my Macbook pro which doesn't have a CD reader. I got the files on the CD but still can't figure out a way to boot it upon start up. Is there any way to make this possible?

*Please exclude solutions including using flash drives. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use flash drive (that is the simple way to do it usually), maybe you can access to your bios settings and select PXE booting (network based solution basically https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preboot_Execution_Environment). But you will need some extra work to set a pxe server to serve your live linux image.